# Is it proper to defined hibernate hbm file with id mapped to non-primary column in table

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have come across a hibernate hbm configuration where id attribute is mapped to a column in table which is not the primary key. The mapping is just used for read and not update. Though this works for most of the cases, I have found some cases where , when queried using get() on this mapping , it throws **org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found**

So my question is :

- If I define a hbm with id mapped to non-primary key in table, can it allow more than two records with same id ?
- At what layer is the primary key constraint checked, hibernate or database ?

Thanks,
Gaurav.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I am not creating a mapping of this kind :-) But came across this in my project and this mapping has has worked till now. In performance testing, I found that for some cases it throws the exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found. So was wondering if the hibernate enforces the ID to be unique, then how can it allow more than one record. And then I discovered that the Id attribute is mapped to non-primary key column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if the column has all the features of a PK:

- unique among all the rows of the table
- immutable

The constraint is enforced at the database level. But Hibernate needs its ID to be unique. So it will choke if two rows have the same ID in database and are loaded in the same session.

I can't see any good reason to use a non-PK column as the ID of an entity, except if you're forced to map a legacy table, which can't change, and doesn't have any PK defined, even if one column or set of columns could be defined as the PK.

Comment: It helped me . Not for legacy purpose but there is postgres sequence generator which is not working with JPA \@Id and Sequence generator.It was always picking already exisiting 'id' for new create operation.So I used non-primary unique key as \@Id.It works fine.